# Переклад "matchmaking" українською мовою

Tags: переклад, from-english

Слово *"matchmaking"* останнім часом часто в бізнес-колах використовується для назви специфічного процесу знаходження контактів. Так називають, наприклад, частину семінару/конференції, під час якої відбувається спілкування тет-а-тет представників різних компаній для налагодження бізнес зв'язків.

Гугл [пропонує](https://translate.google.com.ua/?hl=uk&tab=wT#en/uk/matchmaking) 
*товаришування* та *сватання*, що, звісно, не відповідає вживанню даного терміна у діловому контексті.

English by Oxford Dictionaries [натякає](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/matchmaking) на *романтичні зустрічі*:

> The arranging of marriages or initiation of romantic relationships between others.

Wikipedia [ENG] теж не [пояснює](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matchmaking):

> Matchmaking is the process of matching two or more people together, usually for the purpose of marriage, but the word is also used in the context of sporting events such as boxing, in business, in online video games and in pairing organ donors.

Прошу допомогти знайти влучний український аналог, зауважу, що слова *"переговори"* та/або *"зустрічі"* не досить влучно передають особливе, контекстне значення даного слова.

Comment: Oxford Dictionaries не натякає - "matchmaker" це українською "[сваха](http://sum.in.ua/s/svakha)" у сенсі "жінка, яка займається сватанням, влаштуванням шлюбів".

Answer (score 2):

Наприклад, **парування**.

Словники надають це слово з пікантним відтінком, але на це можна відповісти, що знаходження бізнес-партнера — це також досить інтимний процес.

> [**ПАРУВАННЯ**](http://sum.in.ua/s/paruvannja) 2, я, сер. 1. Дія за значенням парувати 2 і паруватися.
>
> [**ПАРУВАТИСЯ**](http://sum.in.ua/s/paruvatysja), уюся, уєшся, недок.
>
> 2. Знаходити собі пару (див. пара 1 7). —
>
> *Всі до пари, як голубочки, тільки Пріська одинока, — мовила Палагея Тихонівна.. — Значить, не охота паруватися, бо за парою не бував остановки* (Любов Яновська, I, 1959, 257);